# How can I create a program that converts military time into standard time?

Tags: c++

The problem asks to create a program that converts military time to standard. It asks to create a function that will convert it and give out the sample output bellow:

Please enter the time in military time: 1433 
The equivalent regular time is: 2:33 pm

This is what I have up to now, also how can I put the ":" between the time in standard form. Can I use `std::string.insert();` ?

```
void mil_to_reg() {
    unsigned short int time1;
    std::cout << "Please enter the time in military time: ";
    std::cin >> time1;
    unsigned short int time1_ = 1200;
    if (time1 >= 1300 && time1 <= 2400) {
        int standard = time1 - time1_;
        std::string standard_str = std::to_string(standard);
        std::cout << "The equivalent regular time is: "
        << standard << " pm\n";
    }
}
int main() {
    mil_to_reg();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that 1200 is pm and 2400 is am, so you will need more than one `if` statement. You can insert ":" at position `standard.length - 2`.

```
string aorp;
if (time1 >= 1200 && time1 < 2400)
    aorp = " pm\n";
else
    aorp = " am\n";
if (time1 >= 1300 && time1 < 2400)
{
    int standard = time1 - time1_;
    std::string standard_str = std::to_string(standard);   
}
else
    std::string standard_str = std::to_string(time1);
std::cout << "The equivalent regular time is: " << standard_str.insert(standard.length - 2, ":") << aorp;
```

Comment: how can i make the "am" part for example if the user inputs 0100 the standard time should be 1:00 am. i got the pm part but im confused on the am

Comment: Check the first `if` in my answer, it deals with it.

Comment: the compiler keeps telling me that "Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union" what does that mean..

Comment: at which line??

Comment: at this line std::cout << "The equivalent regular time is: " << standard.insert(standard.length - 2, ":") << aorp;

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try it now.